# boost program_options: using zero-parameter options multiple times?

Tags: c++, boost

I am wondering whether it is possible to use zero-parameter options multiple times with boost::program_options.

I have something in mind like this:

```
mytool --load myfile --print_status --do-something 23 --print_status
```

It is easy to get this working with *one* "print_status" parameter, but it is not obvious to me how one could use this option two times (in my case, boost throws an exception if a zero-parameter option is specified more than once).

So, the question is:

**Is there any (simple) way to achieve this with out-of-the box functionality from program_options?**

Right now, it seems this is a drawback of the current program_options implementation.

P.S.:

There have already been similar questions in the past (both over four years old), where no solution was found:

http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2006/08/21631.php

http://benjaminwolsey.de/de/node/103

This thread contains a solution, but it is not obvious whether it is a working one, and it seems rather complex for such a simple feature:

[Specifying levels (e.g. --verbose) using Boost program_options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093579/specifying-levels-e-g-verbose-using-boost-program-options)

Comment: do you want to count how often `--print_status` is specified or just allow it to be added multiple times?

Comment: just allow it to be added multiple times

Comment: in fact, count is not that important - I am writing a pipeline-like data processing application, and I want to be able do zero-parameter processing stages (like "print_status") in between, for an arbitrary amount of times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to count the number of times the option has been specified, it's fairly easy (if a little odd); just declare the variable as `vector<bool>` and set the following parameters:

```
std::vector<bool> example;
// ...
desc.add_options()
    ("example,e",
     po::value(&example)
     ->default_value(std::vector<bool>(), "false")
     ->implicit_value(std::vector<bool>(1), "true")
     ->zero_tokens()
    )
// ...
```

Specifying a `vector` suppresses multiple argument checking; `default_value` says that the vector should by default be empty, `implicit_value` says to set it to a 1-element vector if `-e/--example` is specified, and `zero_tokens` says not to consume any following tokens.

If `-e` or `--example` is specified at least once, `example.size()` will be exactly `1`; otherwise it will be `0`.

[Example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a034f08a2b10b2ff)

If you *do* want to count how many times the option occurs, it's easy enough to write a custom type and validator:

```
struct counter { int count = 0; };
void validate(boost::any& v, std::vector<std::string> const& xs, counter*, long)
{
    if (v.empty()) v = counter{1};
    else ++boost::any_cast<counter&>(v).count;
}
```

[Example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/527232c894ed323a)

Note that unlike in the linked question this doesn't allow additionally specifying a value (e.g. `--verbose 6`) - if you want to do something that complex you would need to write a custom `value_semantic` subclass, as it's not supported by Boost's existing semantics.

Comment: The first example worked for me with a little modification:
`po::value<std::vector<bool> >()
             ->default_value(std::vector<bool>(), "false")
             ->implicit_value(std::vector<bool>(1), "true")
             ->zero_tokens()`